array to string conversion when trying session_set_cookie_params
I'm using PHP 5.6 and when I try to set some cookie parameters in PHP using the session_set_cookie_params function, I get an error stating that I'm trying to convert an array to a string.
This is my code:
session_set_cookie_params([
  'lifetime' => 1800,
  'path' => '/',
  'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
  'secure' => false,
  'httponly' => true,
  'samesite' => 'Strict'
]);

Any clue why this is happening? How can i solve this problem without having to change my php version、？
